# Search and replace macro in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, macros

How do I record (or write) search and replace macro in Netbeans?

I want to record the actions I do in Ctrl+H dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible (Netbeans 6.8).
The only field you can preset is the field "Find What". The other options stay unchanged.
Eventually, if you have a complex regexp to search, you can use the following tip :
caret-end-line insert-break "regexp" selection-begin-line replace  remove-line

Comment: This is not the answer I wanted to hear, but it is true. Not possible with current version. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I ran into somewhat the same problem! Maybe this will ease it up a bit!
http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2008/12/use-regular-expressions-for-search-and.html